# How we use SUM with PREVIOUS is SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012

when I used this I got error:

=SUM(iif(Fields!InitialAPUUsageHrRead.Value="true", "0.0",Fields!Hours_Read_Leg_Data.Value-Previous(Fields!Hours_Read_Leg_Data.Value)))

Comment: What is the error? Are your trying to use it or is it returning an error?

Comment: I got this error:

Comment: The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox55.Paragraph[0].TextRuns[0]' uses a Previous function in an outer aggregate. Previous functions cannot be specified as nested aggregate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSRS won't let you do this. It really doesn't like you breaking out of groups and datasets...

You can try referencing the exact textbox you want to get the value from:
ReportItems!TextBox1.Value
It will grab the box in your current grouping.

If that doesn't work, check out the LOOKUP and LOOKUPSET functions, they might help you accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: Right, I agree with you. I got the right direction. Thanks.